# Time Complexity of Java's NIO StandardOpenOption.Append operation

Tags: java, file, io, nio

The current [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/StandardOpenOption.html#APPEND) for `StandardOpenOption.Append` says:

> If the file is opened for WRITE access then bytes will be written to the end of the file rather than the beginning.````

However, I can't seem to find any further information on how this works internally.

My use case involves *appending* data to a huge file. I currently use `BufferedWriter`, but my understanding is that, if I have some way to maintain a pointer to the end of the file, I can easily append to it, without first traversing from start of file, till end of file.

So, my question is: Does `StandardOpenOption.Append` actually work in a similar method? Or does this also, internally, move to end of file and perform the append?

Comment: Since the size of the file is known already it should be easy to move the "cursor" to the end of the file and append data. The limiting factor probably is your disk i/o here, i.e. how fast those writes can happen (and maybe some OS/FS related factors but those are probably negligible). Also, please define "large" :)

Comment: It is *O(1)*. All the operating system has to do is set the file pointer to the end instead of the beginning. No traversal of the file is required.

Comment: @user207421 If you could please also provide a source for the info (and add your comment as an answer), I could approve the same as the answer for this question. Thank you!

Comment: It's just common sense. The operating system has all the necessary information. Why would it need to traverse the file?